# Is there an implied distribution given the below for where a transaction happens?

Tags: bayesian, inference

Assume you have a buyer and a seller.

You know that the buyer's probability of buying the good at different prices (ie smth like P(B|price) and similarly for the seller P(S|price).

Given you know these you know a transaction happens if both agree - in that case for any given price P(transaction|price) = P(B|price) x P(S|price).

The obvious thing to get P(transaction) is something like P(price) however intuitively this seems wrong. For example, the fact that I know that the buyer wouldn't buy above some max (call it P_max) and the seller wouldn't sell below some min (call it P_min) this means that a transaction at those prices should never be proposed.

If you consider the price to be suggested by an agent (say a real estate broker) then they should maximise the chance that a transaction happens so one "dumb method" would be to say where is P(transaction|price) maximised and present that price.

My sense is that given P(B|price) and P(S|price) are "known" there is an implicit distribution of P(price|transaction) as well from which I'd expect to be able to calculate P(transcation|price).

Not sure what the "right" tags would be - feel free to edit them / add to them.